# compact and convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

I recently have worked on compact convex sets in the context of time series and my question is related to that.
If we have a set 
$$
C=\{\beta_1 X_1 +\beta_2 X_2 +\phi H_1 , |\beta_1|+|\beta_2|+|\phi|\leq K\}
$$
where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and $H_1$  consists of dependent columns(and correlated to $X_1$ and $X_2$). Also $X$ and $H_1$ are bounded. Then, under which conditions can we say that C is a compact and convex set?

Comment: Almost never, I guess, because it looks like it is open in the finite dimensional subspace spanned by $X_1,X_2,H_1$.

Comment: Dear @JohannesHahn, thank you for your reply. I know that in the situation where there are just $X_1$ and $X_2$, the set C is convex and compact. So what makes C so different if there exists H?

Comment: Alright, I was vague. Let me be more clear: The set you've defined *is never* compact in any hausdorff vector space topology. When you say you have proved it, you must have another topology. What topology is that?

Comment: Thank you @JohannesHahn. I have not proved that, it is written in the paper:  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5817v4 on page 6 at the top of the page.

Comment: How about using weak inequality in your definition, instead of strict? Is that what you mean? What are $X_1,X_2$ and $H$? Vectors?

Comment: Thank you @PerAlexandersson. $X_1$, $X_2$ are random variables. precisely $H$  consist of lags of response variable $Y$. Then the regression model is like  $Y_t=f(X_t,Y_{t-1,...,t_n}$. Then $X_1$, $X_2$ and $H$ are vectors.

Comment: @HAMEDHM That is totally different! In that paper the inequality is not strict and of course *that* set is compact because it is the continuous image of a compact set. Here you are asking about a different set!

Comment: Thank you @JohannesHahn I have corrected the mistake. Could you please explain it more?

Comment: There is really not much to explain... $\{(\beta_1,\beta_2,\phi)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid |\beta_1|+|\beta_2|+|\phi|\leq K\}$ is compact and your set is an image of this set under a continuous map.

Comment: thank you @JohannesHahn. What about Convexity?

Comment: The set Johannes defined in the comment above is compact and convex. $C$ is an image of it under a linear transformation. Linear transformations preserve convexity and compactness.

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused. Firstly, is the form that @JohannesHahn has defined is equivalent to the form that I defined? secondly, is it compact and convex with respect to $\beta$'s and $\phi$ or with respect to $X$'s and $H$? third, if assume that $\phi$ consists of $\phi 1, \phi 2$ (and then H consists of two columns), then, is the results the same as above? fourth, I know it is very easy for you but is there any formal proof for convexity and compactness in current case?